# Boxplot tick values for the y-axis in R?

Tags: r, axis, boxplot

I am trying to create a boxplot in R, however, I find that the figure has wrong tick values for the y-axis.

The .rdata is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbgf3mhgd2mjx8o/Mydata2.rdata?dl=0

```
load("Mydata2.rdata",.GlobalEnv)
boxplot(Value~Type+Level, data=Mydata2)
```

As the figure shows, the y-axis is marked "0, 50, 100", however, my data range from  -36.9 to 133.7. I wonder how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: The y axis has a range from about -50 to 150 from what I can see. What do you want the tickmarks to be?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, you are correct. But the figure I create shows "0,50,100", I do not know why.

Comment: @YangYang This is a misleading title and I suggest you change it. Boxplot does not create a "wrong y-axis"; the root of the issue stems from a wrong understanding of axis limits and axis tick (labels).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I used `min`, `mean`, and `max` for the tick marks. You can set them to any value manually or even have more than 3 ticks. `yaxt="n"` prevents the default tick marks and then by using `axis` and setting the side to `2` (`axis(2,...`) I add my desired tick marks. Read about `?axis` in R.

```r
boxplot(Value~Type+Level, yaxt="n", data=Mydata2)
axis(2, 
     at=round(c(min(Mydata2$Value), mean(Mydata2$Value), max(Mydata2$Value)),1),
     labels = T)
```

[image]

#### Follow up question: How the default tick marks are computed?

*"When `at = NULL`, pretty tick mark locations are computed internally (the same way [`axTicks(side)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.0/topics/axTicks) would)."*

So, your code is working. Default tick marks are picked by `boxplot` so it is prettier (well pretty is subjective).

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why my codes do not work?

Comment: @YangYang Updated my answer. Your code works fine. The default behavior does not care about the exact limits of your data. You can read more here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.0/topics/axis

Comment: @M-M I guess you wanted to say `pretty is subjective`.

Comment: @yarnabrina well, I wished it was objective. My dream just slipped out of my mouth (my fingers actually, as we type here). Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods:

1. Set each tickmark individually via `axis`'s `at` argument (`at` is a numeric vector defining each tickmark):

```r
boxplot(Value~Type+Level, yaxt="n", data=Mydata2)
tickmarks = c(min(Mydata2$Value), max(Mydata2$Value))
axis(2, at = round(tickmarks,1))
```

2. Define the range for your tickmarks via `boxplot`'s `ylim` argument. So, to set the range for your tickmarks between -40 and 140:

```r
boxplot(Value~Type+Level, data=Mydata2, ylim=c(-40,140))
```

Method #2 works sometimes but not always. Method #1 is more reliable and customizable and should therefore be used more often.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why my codes do not work?

Comment: Well, it's not that your code does not work.  It's just that your code doesn't know what exactly you want your axes to be, so you have to tell it via one of these two methods.  Otherwise, if you don't tell it what you want your axes to be, your code will just take a guess (eg. making your axes 0,50,100).

Comment: Hi, I tried your second method, but it does not work as `yaxt="n"` will remove the whole y-axis. Could you please check?

Comment: As shown above, you should merely remove the `yaxt="n"` argument, which suppresses the y-axis.

Comment: Hi, I tried `boxplot(Value~Type+Level, data=Mydata2, ylim=c(-40,140))`, but it still does not work in my case.

Comment: @MatthewAnderson OP wants the tick marks not the limit.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my vague expression. After I run `boxplot(Value~Type+Level, data=Mydata2, ylim=c(-40,140))`, it gives me the same figure shown in my question. The y-axis tick values are still "0,50,100", which is not correct, thanks.

Comment: Interesting. On my machine, the tickmarks did change. Refer to method #1 then.